# How can select name in the list?

Tags: python

I want to print Ava, Emma, Olivia, Sophia.
How should I print?

```
def unique_names(names1, names2):
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    names1 = ["Ava", "Emma", "Olivia"]
    names2 = ["Olivia", "Sophia", "Emma"]
    print(unique_names(names1, names2))
```

Comment: Do you have any code that shows any effort at solving your issue? This looks like a homework assignment, but you haven't shown us whether you have tried to fill in the content of your `unique_names` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution is the following:

```
def unique_names(names1, names2):
    return ", ".join(set(names1 + names2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    names1 = ["Ava", "Emma", "Olivia"]
    names2 = ["Olivia", "Sophia", "Emma"]
    print(unique_names(names1, names2))
```

Prints

```
Sophia, Olivia, Emma, Ava
```